# Handling cascade with CakePHP or MySQL FKs?

Tags: mysql, performance, cakephp, cascade

In a performance and coherence point of view, should I let cakephp handle cascade delete, or should I define them with foreign keys in MySQL ?

Comment: Does your application use MySQL foreign keys to enforce referential integrity? Would your data ever be deleted from another "application" than Cakephp (e.g., commandline, MySQL tools, php)?

Comment: Well, I was looking to use FKs to enforce refential integrity, but I read somewhere that I would not be able to delete the row if it's reference in an other place without an action set on the FK. So I finally was going to let Cakephp handle it ; the other problem was with delete on mulptiple records, as CakePHP has to retrieve each singular ID to delete in cascade, and this can go very far while MySQL can do it way faster. But I don't think I will have any user-sided deleteAll() in my application, so I guess it should be ok. Tell me what you think about that

Comment: (And other than MySQL, I shouldn't be using any other tools)

Comment: I would implement within MySQL since you are creating the Foreign Keys anyway. You gain the additional benefit that you can, at any future time, delete a record from outside Cakephp and have the cascading functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Databases are created for handling those things, it's an integral part of what they do so they know how to do it most efficiently and there's no reason to reinvent the wheel - let alone managing the code and the tests for it.

Furthermore, if you design your database well you're guaranteed its integrity no matter what. Even if you mess up at some point in your code the db will catch it and save the day.

So I don't see any reason going away from the db.

Comment: Well, in fact I thought about it and I will use CakePHP, as sometimes I want just to soft delete associated records (setting a field deleted to 1), sometimes I need to delete a file associated with the record. So I kinda can't use MySQL CASCADE.

Comment: A soft delete still is compatible with db foreign keys. You just add your extra field and add a behaviour to do the trick. The problems that would arise when you actually delete a referenced field won't disappear unless you're committed to never ever delete anything.

Comment: Yes, that's not an option I can commit to unfortunately. Thanks anyways